# Make a URL + field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to custom my URL.

```
<a href="/2017/?post_type=issue_number"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

I want that the 2017 in URL is `<?php the_title(); ?>`.

Some as this :

```
<a href="/<?php the_title(); ?>/?post_type=issue_number"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

It is possible??

Comment: Antonio, I think you would have to make sure that "the_title()" provides a URLEncoded string format, which in fact, would not always be good to read for users. In fact, maybe you should use a different function? Whatever: I think your question is whether something like this is possible for you, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

`<?php echo basename(get_permalink()); ?>` would be a better approach I think. That basically outputs the slug portion (not the whole URL)...which is basically the title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URLs in your WordPress config to use "Post slugs".

Comment: Is there a way to custom URL ?

Comment: Yes, it is all configurable within the wordpress admin screen

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

With this code

```
<a href="/<?php echo the_title(); ?>/?post_type=issue_number" >
     <?php the_title(); ?></a>
```